# Synchronize fresh reads and memory barrier

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, java-memory-model

I have read the following article http://javaexp.blogspot.com/2007/12/difference-between-volatile-and.html and understand that :

> In fact synchronized synchronizes the whole of thread memory with "main" memory.

I have a doubt if I have the following :

```
public class A {
int count;

    public synchronized int methodA() {
        return count++;
    }

   public int methodB() {
        return count++;
    }
}
```

is the thread in methodA always reads the latest value for count ? or that is not guaranteed because methodB is not synchronized ?

Answer (score 0):

Thread can get wrong values of cout++ as this is not correct way of multithreaded programming.

Consider the scenario, where Thread_1 and Thread_2 both calls methodB at same time and get the value 5 say and both then increase the value so actually value should be 7 , but now the values which other thread3 will get the value  6 due to wrong multithrerading.

Comment: I know that but the question about if Thread in methodA will have visibility on changes from a thread on methodB or not, in otherwords will changes on methodB always be in sync in methodA

Comment: It is not logical to write this , As Thread can always get wrong value .

Comment: yes but the main question is to know if the values in synchronized block are visible with non synchronized one , so is ThreadA above will have wrong value as B not syncrhonized ?